# self-referential association has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphism

user can follow a another user or a company.How to maintain association in one table which is followerships which is working fine for user model? I want to use same table for company also.

Exixting code.
I am using the self referential association for follower functionality.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :followerships
   has_many :following, :through => :followerships


   has_many :inverse_followerships, :class_name => "Followership", :foreign_key => "following_id"
   has_many :inverse_following, :through => :inverse_followerships, :source => :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be any help for following both users and companies but have you seen Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)?

Basically he walks you through building a twitter like app including following other users and being followed. It could just be helpful to see the best practice on this sort of thing as his code is really clean.

[Chapter 11: Following users](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top)